# Aggregate function -Avg is not working in my sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my query I need to display date and average age:

```
SELECT (SYSDATE-rownum) AS DATE,
       avg((SYSDATE - rownum)- create_time) as average_Age
FROM items
group by (SYSDATE-rownum)
```

But my output for average age is not correct. It's simply calculating/displaying  the output of  `(SYSDATE - rownum)- create_time` but not calculating the average of them though I use: `avg((SYSDATE - rownum)- create_time)`.

Can someone tell me why the aggregate function `AVG` is not working in my query and what might be the possible solution

Comment: Please show sample data, and expected output.  Why are you subtracing rownum from a date?

Comment: Can you please show the table structure with example data?

Comment: The group by sysdate-rownum assures that you are grouping by row,so of course the average is the singe value for that row.

Answer (score 0):

In the select clause you are using both an non-aggregate expression as wel as an aggregate expression. By dropping the `(SYSDATE-rownum) AS DATE` statemant you would generate an outcome over the whole data set. In that way the `avg` is calculated over the whole data set ... and not just per single record retrieve.
Then you might drop the `group by` too. In the end you just keep the avg statement

```
SELECT avg((SYSDATE - rownum)- create_time) as average_Age
FROM items
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to think on rows or group on which you need avg. this column will come in group by clause. as a simple thing if there is 5 rows with age of 20, 10, 20, 30 then avg will be (80/4=20) i.e. 20. so I think you need to fist calculate age by (sysdate - create_time).

```
eg.select months_between(sysdate,create_date)/12 cal3 from your_table
```

and then there will be outer query for avg on group.